# Opening outbound ports to send email via SMTP

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, smtp, system.net.mail

Does Sending email via external SMTP from  my web application (asp.net mvc) using .net framework class ( System.Net.Mail ) require opening any outbound ports from windows firewall on my server (which port must be opened)

i am experiencing a success trials to send from my local machine (development) but failed to send on the production live server (with no errors or exceptions thrown)

using the same mail server info and recipient email:

- on my local machine .. it sends with no errors and received at the recipient side
- on live server .. it sends with no errors but never received at the recipient side

so what’s wrong

Comment: If you are not getting an exception, and you are confident that your logging and exception handling are good enough that you *would* see an exception, then it's unlikely to be a firewall issue - the firewall preventing outbound SMTP traffic would typically cause a SocketException or similar.

Comment: Does your SMTP client library support logging of the SMTP requests/responses? That might give you a clue. If it doesn't you may be able to use WireShark or similar to intercept the SMTP traffic.

Comment: (Just to check though - you *do* have good logging and exception handling, right? And your logging is explicitly telling you that the email was successfully sent, right? Maybe edit your question to include some code to demonstrate this....)